# Guice: binding interface to instance created by dynamic proxies

Tags: java, dynamic, proxy, guice

I am looking for a solution to bind any sub-interface of a tagging interface to an instance created by a java dynamic proxy. The dynamic proxy knows how to implement each method in the sub-interfaces. The problem is that I want to do it automatically for all sub-interfaces requested.

```
interface ITaggingInterface() {
}

interface ISubInterface extends ITaggingInterface {
  String doSomething();
}
```

The ISubInterface can be implemented by using a proxy:

```
ISubInterface si = (ISubInterface)Proxy.newProxyInstance(classloader, new Class<?>[]{ISubInterface.class}, invocationHandler);
```

How do I instrument my injector so that every time an sub-interface is requested it uses the dynamic proxy to create the implementation.

I know I can bind each and every sub-interface separately, but this is what I want to avoid. I am looking for something similar to:

```
bind(any-sub-interface).toProvider(provider-that-creates-proxy-instance);
```

Is this possible with guice ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in the seamless way you're looking for. At it's heart, Guice's bindings are like a `Map<Key, Provider>`. This makes it difficult to bind "any type with this annotation", "any subtype of this type", or other matcher-like bindings like that.

If you're okay with using method/field injection and a custom annotation instead of @Inject, you might try using [custom injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections), which would allow you to inspect injected classes and manipulate them as needed the way that the above link does with @InjectLogger.

Other than restructuring your requirements, my personal solution would be something like this:

```
/** Injectable. */
class TaggingInterfaceFactory {
  /** Guice can always inject the injector. */
  @Inject Injector injector;

  <T> T getInstanceOrProxy(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(ITaggingInterface.class)) {
      return createYourProxyHere(clazz);
    } else {
      return injector.getInstance(clazz);
    }
  }
}
```